Is Directory to SubDirectory more of a composition or inheritance?
In object-oriented programming, there are two main relationships between objects.

Inheritance (is-a-relation)
Composition (has-a-relation / also called containment)

For inheritance, one can have a relationship between different file types. Text files and bitmap files are files. Because of this, one could code
class File
{
public:
  void GetFileSize() { /* Implementation */ }
};
class BMPFile :public File {};
class TextFile:public File {};

By saying inheritance, the GetFileSize implementation in the base class (File) can be reused in derived classes BMPFile and TextFile.
This is basic code reusability using inheritance.
For composition, one can have a relationship between a directory and files.
class Directory
{
  std::list<File> list_of_files;
}

Now comes the main part of my question.
a) What is the relationship between a directory and a sub-directory?
b) Since a directory contains a sub-directory, it is definitely a composition. Is my understanding correct?
c) Since a sub-directory has all the properties of a directory, it is also an inheritance. Is my understanding correct?
d) I believe a sub-directory has inheritance relationship with a directory because of the following analogy.
Let us say I want to have a Directory class that has the following behaviour/properties
class Directory
{
public:
  virtual bool HasSubDirectory {/*Implementation code*/}
  virtual void CreateSubDirectory(std::string dirName){/*Implementation code*/}
  virtual void DeleteSubDirectory(){/*Implementation code*/}
  virtual std::list<SubDirectory> ListAllSubDirectories{/*Implementation code*/}
};
class SubDirectory : public Directory{}

By making a SubDirectory inheriting from Directory, I can achieve good code reusability. (I am also aware of code reusability through delegation in case of composition. But may be for this example inheritance is better I believe?)
e) There is a composition design pattern in Gang of Four, which is for a relationship between tree kind of a structure. Is the above example is a good candidate for composition design pattern ?
I am changing the Directory class as this
class Directory
{
public:
  virtual bool HasSubDirectory =0;
  virtual void CreateSubDirectory(std::string dirName)=0;
  virtual void DeleteSubDirectory()=0;
  virtual std::list<Directory*> ListAllSubDirectories=0;
};
class SubDirectory : public Directory{
  public:
  virtual bool HasSubDirectory {/*Implementation code*/}
  virtual void CreateSubDirectory(std::string dirName){/*Implementation code*/}
  virtual void DeleteSubDirectory(){/*Implementation code*/}
  virtual std::list<Directory*> ListAllSubDirectories{/*Implementation code*/}
}

I can get example for inheritance/composition. But I want an example which contains both. Hence I wanted to know whether this is a good candidate.

It is both. A subdirectory is a directory (a special kind of directory, namely one that has a parent), and it also contains a subdirectory (the child directory inside it). The issue is that you are changing the question. "If X is a subdirectory, is X a directory?" Yes. "If X is a subdirectory, does it contain a directory Y?" Also yes. But the two questions are not similar. One is about X and X. The other is about X and Y.

Thanks @Raymond Chen.
But then to perform code reusability I can use a SubDirectory as a Directory and simply call functions in Directory for all Subdirectory elements of Directory right ?

You could go simpler. You don't need to go down to subdirectories to find something that contains its base class. A directory is a special type of file (literally under Linux; I'm not sure if Windows terminology goes that far).

One problem with this question is that it assumes that there is only one way to do things (and only two possible relationships). Sometimes there are conflicting design concerns that influence whether or not inheritance takes place. In the end, the relationship between class A and class B is whatever you define it to be. So, it's possible this is too opinion-based for Stack Overflow (but I'll think about it some more before casting a close vote). On the other hand, maybe an answer saying it's up to you is appropriate. Plus, you are using a known, concrete example, which is helpful.

Hi  @JaMiT, I do not mean it should be done in a same way I believe. I just wanted to get clarify whether my suggested way is fine (SubDirectory inheriting all functionalities in a Directory) It may be an opinion based since it is an open ended question (there may not be a perfect unique answer in all situation) . But I just would like to know other's opinion or some thing I am missing.

Hi @JaMiT, Even Windows treat a directory as a  file with some special attributes. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). But that is for a naming convention . But I want it to be separate for this discussion , because for a user they are really a different things. For OS (File System implementation part)they may be a similar type. I am talking here about user perspective.

Not just a naming convention. Everything is a file in the Unix family.

Hi @JaMiT, sorry for my word (naming convention). Even Windows File System  considers Directory as a special type of File. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). Link says naming a file. But then also says Directory as a special type of File. Hence I believe it is similar to Linux.

"What is the relationship between a directory and a sub-directory?" you see, this is why OOP has a terrible reputation. All of these are the wrong questions. You model your problem as necessary, categorizing your problem into all the patterns, relationships and whatever does not help. An example of a correct question is "how does std::filesystem work, what are its design goals and what are its limitations"?

@GajananaDS "I am talking here about user perspective." -- Your question does not mention this. If you add a precise version of this to your question, I think your question becomes "From the perspective of someone who views a subdirectory as a directory that can contain other directories, is it correct to say that a subdirectory is a directory that potentially has a directory?" Which comes back to the answer being whatever you, the designer, defined it to be.

Hi @Passer By, you are talking about Implementation perspective, which is on the File System Implementation side. I am talking about a User perspective. Any normal user (a layman) who uses Computer , considers a Directory & File as a different entity right ? I am talking in that scenario.

Hi @Passer By, for a user file & directory is a different things right.
A Directory can have files but not vice versa.
A directory you can always open it (by double clicking) . Then it will show sub directories . User can visualize those sub directories.
A file can be opened only if File viewer (PDF Reader, MSWORD etc) only if those applications are present on the system.
Hence as a user, there are many differences  between them to treat them as different ones.

Hi @JaMiT, thanks for correcting the question. Yes whatever you mentioned is what I meant, although I might not have framed the question very precisely.

"a) What is the relationship between a directory and a sub-directory?" IMO, there are the same :) "is-a-relation" might also "be an instance of". In the same way having class BmpFile wrong (as renaming file seems problematic).

Let's look at some example of Directory class (interface with abstract methods):
class Directory {
    public:
    virtual std::list<Directory> subDirectories();
    virtual void dele();
    virtual void addDirectory(std::string withName);
};


Composition and inheritance are relationships between two classes, but as you can see in the code we don’t have a Subdirectory class, and therefore we can’t talk about the corresponding relationships.
We will have implementations of the Directory interface (inheritance relationship), for example FileSystemDirectory, which will encapsulate its path in the file system (composition relationship), but this will be a composition between the Directory class and the class representing the path in the file system.
By writing the method std::list<string> ListAllSubDirectories, you didn't actually use an object-oriented approach, you just returned a list of strings (not directories).


Considering the edited part of the question. The Subdirectory type makes no sense, if it is an interface, it does not contain any additional methods, if it is a class, it will encapsulate the same as the base class and have the same behavior.

Hi @nik0x1, updated the question with missing parts. Thanks

@GajananaDS Having the SubDirectory type makes no sense (it doesn't have any additional functionality).

Hi @nik0x1, yes you are right. But then I can make Directory as an abstract class and move all implementation to SubDirectory . I think it will be a composite design pattern ?

@GajananaDS If we take as a basis the abstract class I defined - Directory and the implementation - FileSystemDirectory, then this will not be a composite design pattern because FileSystemDirectory will not encapsulate a list of directories (the class will encapsulate the path to the directory in the file system). It is also worth noting that the class name SubDirectory in this case is semantically incorrect.

First of all, let me clarify few general C++ rules.
You should never use public inheritance for code reuse (note that protected inheritance is the same as public inheritance). You can use private inheritance for that. Private inheritance has absolutely nothing to do with public/protected inheritance, although they both contain word "inheritance". Private inheritance is basically the same as composition. That is how you reuse code. Usually, composition should be preferred over private inheritance because it is more expressive, but there are plausible uses of private inheritance as well. Two that I can think of are: having data members that do not have a unique address (but since C++20 there is [[no_unique_address]] attribute) and encapsulated virtual functions. The point is, if you think "code reuse", you will probably want to use composition/private inheritance.
On the other hand, before using public inheritance, you should ask the question: Can my derived class always be treated as the base class? "is-a relationship" is a bit misleading term for public inheritance because human language is quite peculiar. The most common example is regarding penguins and birds. We, humans, decided to put penguins into category "bird". However, in regards to flying, penguins can't be treated as birds because they can't fly. To us, penguin is a bird, but you should not use public inheritance to express that. Because client code will, sooner or later, try to make your penguins fly. Therefore, when you say "Text files and bitmap files are files", think again. Is there any functionality of file that text_file or bitmap_file do not support? If yes, you need to rethink your strategy. The best approach is to have an abstract class base_file without that extra functionality and then derive file, text_file and bitmap_file from it. Also, if you are using public inheritance, be careful to always either mark you destructor virtual or make it protected.
Now, in regards to your question. I suspect that you want composition/private inheritance because you talk about "good code reusability". If this was a case for public inheritance, you would think in terms of having default implementation (in Directory) and overrides (in SubDirectory).
In short, if, where you have written /*Implementation code*/, you want to put default implementation that will be different from the corresponding implementation in SubDirectory, use public inheritance. If you want to reuse code written in /*Implementation code*/, use composition/private inheritance.
And of course, disclaimer: this is general approach. There are million exceptions and good reasons to go wild. But then again, we all think our case is special, while in truth, it is a very small chance that it indeed is.

Hi @lobelk, thanks for the feedback. Regarding TextFile/BmpFile, yes those files may have different properties unique to them. For example Rotate/Fill may only applies to Bitmap file where as Change Font/Bold and other things only applies to Text file. In such cases composition is a better choice.

Hi @lobelk, I have intentionally added GetFileSize property only for File (although ReadFile/WriteFile can also be there) for the inheritance property. When there are more properties or behaviours that contradicts between different subclasses then inheritance may go messy.

Hi @lobelk, I believe there is nothing wrong in public inheritance(if it is really wrong then language might not have allowed it in the first place right) But I do agree , there will be more abuse than use, since it is difficult to get it right most of the time.

@GajananaDS I think you have missed the point. If TextFile/BmpFile have properties unique to them, public inheritance is still fine. It is not fine if File has properties that TextFile/BmpFile do not. Public inheritance means that each and every TextFile/BmpFile can be treated as File but not that every File can be treated as TextFile/BmpFile. In simplified words: derived classes can extend the interface but should not restrict it. So, the properties that you have mentioned do not rule out public inheritance by itself.

@GajananaDS I have never said there is something wrong with public inheritance. Only that public inheritance should not be used for code reuse, bur for code extension.

Hi @lobelk. Your statement "public inheritance should not be used code reuse, but for code extension" that makes sense.
